# Javascript 'for loop' not incremented correctly within AJAX subfunction

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop

I have a javascript that interacts with a database in the following way (refer to code below):

1. Gets into a loop that runs through an array called fruits().
2. For each fruit, the php script getFruitData.php is called with one fruit as argument (and then it uses that string to return data about that fruit from a MySQL database).
3. Lists the data once returned. Have excluded that code as it's not where the problem is.

The problem: the 'num' for loop is acting fishy. In the ajax function call it uses the correct number (0, 1 and 2 respectively), so I'm sending the right fruits to the database and get the right info back. But inside the ajax 'success' function, 'num' **is always** 3 (the length of the fruits array). This is weird, as the returned results is displayed one by one when I run the code.

Anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong? Have also tried both while/for loops with a global num variable that I increment inside the loop, but it comes with the same result. It's impossible to get the loop value of 'num' into the ajax response function.

Technically I could of course pass the num value over to php and then return it, that would work, but there must be a more elegant way of doing this and I also want to know what I'm doing wrong. Suggestions?

```
<body>
<button id="display" value="try"> Goho!</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#display").click(function()
    {
        var fruits=["Apple","Orange","Banana"];

        for(num=0; num<fruits.length;num++)
      {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getFruitData.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            // The variable here gets the correct num value (0, 1 or 2)
            data: {variable:fruits[num]},
            success: function( response )
            {
              var dbEntries = $.map(response, function(el) { return el });
              // When printing 'response', the correct data is displayed.
              window.alert (response);
              // num is always 3 here! (length of the array)
              window.alert(num);
            }
        });
      }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `async: false` in ajax call, this is not recommended but this may resolve your problem .

Comment: @JaydipJ This is the worst way to solve the problem.

Comment: ES6: `for(num=0; num<fruits.length;num++) { let j = num; ... window.alert(j); }`

Comment: @Xufox Yes I know, That's why I already mentioned that this is not recommened.

Comment: Thanks for help. Noticed the comment that this is a duplicate question. Sorry for newbe question, but should I remove it?

Comment: @Marcus `for(let num = 0;`… is much better in this scenario.

Comment: @Zooma Only questions closed as off-topic need to be removed, duplicates are sometimes useful, if a user has the same problem and finds the dupe first; then he could be properly redirected to the dupe target. I’d say, it’s up to you.

Comment: @Marcus thanks for solution. Found it on the other link as well: By simply adding "let" to the for clause everything started to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for info.